# Ionic 4 cannot navigate to non tab page from tabs page untill the app is restarted or location.reload()

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a tabbed app. When the app is run first time I am unable to navigate to non tabbed page. this.router.navigate(["non_tabbed_page"]) like this no error is shown in console.

```js
goToCart(){
  this.router.navigate(['appointment-detail']);
}
```

This is my tab module

```js
{ path: 'landing-page', loadChildren: '../landing-page/landing-page.module#LandingPagePageModule' },
{ path: 'service-details', loadChildren: '../service-details/service- details.module#ServiceDetailsPageModule' },
{ path: 'myappointments', loadChildren:'../myappointments/myappointments.module#MyappointmentsPageModule' },
{ path: 'mycart', loadChildren:'../mycart/mycart.module#MycartPageModule' }
```

When I restart the app or refresh the page it is working fine

Comment: You forgot to add a slash before your route? `this.router.navigate(['/appointment-detail']);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not the issue when the app is restarted it is working fine. Also I have added a / but still on the first run its not working.